# Why doesn't my ConcurrencyCheck work when I use UseInMemoryDatabase?

Tags: database, .net-core, concurrency, in-memory-database

I use in memory database for unit tests.

In entry I have:

```
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

After change RowVersion, SaveChanges don't throw exception.
If I use SqlServer all works ok.

What can I do with this? I will not use sql Server in unitTests

Answer (score 0):

The InMemory provider does not always behave like a relational database.

By calling UseInMemoryDatabase(), you are getting something light-weight that *approximates* connecting to your SQL Server database, but without all the overhead of actual database connections and I/O operations.

Much like using Mocks, for the vast majority of our testing this won't matter.  The basics like adding records and reading them back work fine.

However if you want to test against something that behaves more like your SQL Server (e.g. Checking referential integrity constraints or optomistic concurrency) then you should consider using SQLite in-memory mode instead.

Check out this microsoft article on [testing with SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite).